# Designing Module

Tags: oop, design-patterns, c#-3.0

I have a list of modules say 1, 2, 3, and so on. And I have a list of validations say A, B, C, D, and so on. Each module needs to perform some validations ex:-

- module 1 will need to perform A and B validation,
- module 2 will need to perform A, B, and C validation
- module 3 will need to perform B and D validation

So could you tell which best design pattern I should follow in .net core so that I can perform the same efficiently? Some code samples will also help preferably in c#, but Java will also work.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question without more concrete details of what is a validation. Also, do the validations tend to change (modules need to use different validations dynamically, or there are new modules/validations that can be added later)?

Answer (score 0):

If it's solely about validation, then I do not think you need to worry yourself about design patterns.
You may want to look at action filters or extension methods in C# depending on the complexity of what problems you're trying to solve.

**NB: Design patterns actually solve problems like testability and scalability of your applications.**